# Construct camel route based on a timer and a direct route

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to implement a route with camel to satisfy two requirements respectively:

- Start route a specific time in the day (3 A.M) with quartz
- Consume from another route (direct:myOtherRoute)

I already have a route which consumes from direct:myOtherRoute, what i want to acheive now is the addition of start timer.

```
from("direct:myOtherRoute")
            .marshal()
            .zipFile()
            .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant(endpointsURLs.get(EXTRACT_ZIP_FILENAME)))
            .log("Generate ZIP")
            .to("file:" + endpointsURLs.get(EXTRACT_ZIP_DIR) + "?doneFileName=" + endpointsURLs.get(EXTRACT_ZIP_TRIGGER));
```

Comment: Have a look at route policies https://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html - you could set a startup and shutdown time. If what you want is to drain a consumer once and once only, this won't work, as you need to leave the route alive at least long enough to drain your consumer, and you won't necessarily know how long that needs to be, so need to err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 0):

a dirty way to handle this is can run a TimerTask in your camel Builder and addRouteDefinitions or suspendRoute your route. if your problem not solved tell to show my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please, have you had a look at:

[Apache Camel : Quartz2](https://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html)

```
package com.test.camel.quartz2;

import org.apache.camel.spring.SpringRouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class QuartzTest extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?cron=0+0+3+?+*+*+*").to("direct:myOtherRoute");

        from("direct:myOtherRoute").log("Running");
    }

}
```

I have added full test class that can be used with spring-boot. Remember to import maven dependency!

Bonus: to create your cron pattern you can use the following website
[cron-expression-generator-quartz](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)
and remember to replace spaces with "+" symbol as stated in the camel quartz2 page

---

NOTE: If you need quartz 1.x compatibility use the following instead:[Apache Camel : Quartz](https://camel.apache.org/quartz.html)